# Getting error with time format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting format error when changing time in python.

This works fine

`datetime.datetime.strptime('01:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time()`

but this gives error

`datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time()`

> time data '00:00AM' does not match format '%I:%M%p'

Comment: Have you tried this datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time(). Just a guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) I found:

> %I    Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   01, 02, ..., 12

So I think `00:00AM` should be represented as `12:00PM`. Or you can use `%H` mentioned by fahad.

I think it's not an issue of **12-hour clock**. When using `%I`, you have to start  recording hour from **1** not **0**, that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

%I can be used only for 12 hour clock

For 24 hour clock

Try this

> datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00AM', '%H:%M%p').time()